# What is wrong with my testing Player Class in Blackjack Java

Tags: java, computer-science, blackjack

I am trying to test my player class properly, I have almost done it but I am having issues with my **p1.setPlayerHand** method. This is the following code I have used for my player class:

**Player Class:**

```
 package model;

  public class Player
 {
private String PlayerName;
private Hand PlayerHand;
private boolean Dealer;

public Player(String name)
{
    PlayerName = name;
    PlayerHand = new Hand();
    Dealer = false;
}

public void setName (String name)
{
    this.PlayerName = name;
}

public String getName()
{
    return PlayerName;
}

public void setDealer (Boolean dealer)
{
    this.Dealer = dealer;
}

public boolean getDealer()
{
    return Dealer;
}

public void setPlayerHand (Hand hand)
{
    this.PlayerHand = hand;
}

public void getHand()
{
    PlayerHand.displayCardsinHand();
}

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Player p1 = new Player("player1");
    Hand h = new Hand();
    //System.out.println(p1);
    p1.setName("BARRY");

    System.out.println(p1.getName());
    p1.setDealer(false);
    System.out.println(p1.getDealer());

            //this is the error that is preventing my program to run
    p1.setPlayerHand(h.addCard(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, CardRank.ACE)));
    p1.getHand();
}
  }
```

The following error I receive (after testing the Player Class) is this:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: The method setPlayerHand(Hand) in the type Player is not applicable for the arguments (void)
at model.Player.main(Player.java:57)**

This is the Hand Class underneath (that is linked to the Player Class):

**Hand Class:**

```
package model;

import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Random;

public class Hand

{
private Vector<Card> hand;

public Hand()
{
    hand = new Vector<Card>();
}

public void addCard(Card c)
{

    hand.add(c);
}

public void displayCardsinHand()
{
    for (int card = 0; card < hand.size(); card++)
    {
            System.out.println(hand.elementAt(card));
    }
}

public int getCardsinHand()
{
    return hand.size();
}

  public Card getCard(int position)
  {
    if(position >= 0 && position < hand.size())
        return (Card)hand.elementAt(position);
    else
        return null;
  } 

  public int getScore()
  {
    int value = 0;
    boolean ace = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++)
    {
        Card c;
        c = getCard(i);
        value = value + c.getRankValue();

        if(c.getRankValue() == 1)
        {
            ace = true;
        }
    }

    if(ace == true && value + 10 <= 21)
    {
        value = value + 10;
    }

    return value;   
}
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Hand h = new Hand();
    System.out.println(h);

    h.displayCardsinHand();

    System.out.println(h.getCardsinHand());
    h.addCard(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, CardRank.ACE));
    System.out.println(h.getCardsinHand());
    h.addCard(new Card(Suit.SPADES, CardRank.JACK));
    System.out.println(h.getCardsinHand());
    h.addCard(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, CardRank.QUEEN));
    System.out.println(h.getCardsinHand());
    h.addCard(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, CardRank.KING));
    System.out.println(h.getCardsinHand());
    System.out.println(h.getCardsinHand());
    h.displayCardsinHand();
    h.getCard(1);

    System.out.println(h.getScore());
}

  }
```

I have tried modifying the **p1.setPlayerHand** testing numerous times. I appreciate any advice and tips on how to solve this issue, thank you.
If my code is too long for this post then I will gladly accept any advice on what I should do to cut it short (for future reference).
If anyone here required to see any other classes that I wrote (that may help them help me solve this error) then please notify me on here, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The method `addCard` doesn't return anything `(void)`. So you can't pass the result of this method to `setPlayerHand(Hand)`. That's what you're doing.

Comment: Additionally, the runtime error is telling you that the error was detected at compile time. You should have seen an error message when compiling the code.

Answer (score 1):

The code should compile and run if you change

```
p1.setPlayerHand(h.addCard(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, CardRank.ACE)));
```

to

```
h.addCard(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, CardRank.ACE));
p1.setPlayerHand(h);
```

This is because the `setPlayerHand` method needs to be passed an object of type `Hand`, but the `addCard` method doesn't return anything (it's declared as `void`).